# EntityManager type in spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-transactions, hibernate-entitymanager

I have spring project at which most of the service layer are injected with entityManager

```
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;
```

the configuration for the DB

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${spring.datasource.driverClassName}" />
    .

</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan="com.wsg.admin.api.model"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter">

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            .
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

how i can get the type of the entity manager (Extended or Transnational scoped) ?

Answer (score -1):

you can refer this sample code :

```
<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
<bean id="hibernateJpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.demo.test.entity" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="hibernateJpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="${database.jdbc.driver.class}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.url" value="${database.jdbc.url}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.username" value="${database.user}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.password" value="${database.password}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}" />
            <entry key="show_sql" value="true" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.is-lazy"
                value="true" />
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="${database.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but how can i find the answer ?

Comment: you can use annotation `@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)` for Transnational and use `@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)` for Extended entity manager before `EntityManager entityManager;`